# Can return keyword be omitted in a return statement?

Tags: c++

I recently come across the below piece of code in this [Apache Axis tutorial example.](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/docs/om_tutorial.html)

```
int main()
{
    int status = AXIS2_SUCCESS;

    axutil_env_t *env = NULL;
    axutil_allocator_t *allocator = NULL;
    env = create_environment();

    status = build_and_serialize_om(env);

    (status == AXIS2_FAILURE)
    {
        printf(" build AXIOM failed");
    }

    axutil_env_free(env);

     0;
}
```

What i don't understand is the `0;` at the end.
Is that return statement without the return keyword?

I tried the below piece of code to test this in Visual Studio.

```
int main()
{
    0; // in the second run, replaced 0 with 28
}
```

Both programmes ran without any problems. But `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` at
windows command line returned 0 for both.

But the below piece of code

```
int add()
{
    0;
}
```

causes

> Error  1   error C4716: 'add' : must return a value

I understand that return value `0` is implicitly added for the `main()`.

I don't have a problem including the return keyword at all, but I am
porting the Axis2/C Library to a C++ project. And there are many instances
where I encountered `0;`

Why is the above syntax causing this undefined behavior?

Comment: "there are many instances where I encountered 0;" You have to fix them all. "Why is the above syntax causing this undefined behavior?" Because that's what the standard says.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that whatever compiler was being used would take the `0;`, load 0 into a register as part of the evaluation of the expression, and then find that 0 there when getting the return value later. In any case, I would stay away from that with a ten foot pole.

Comment: @chris That's really hardcore ;)

Comment: @vsoftco, I have no idea how far back you'd have to go to find a compiler that doesn't optimize that, even with no optimizations turned on. It makes me cringe a bit thinking about optimization there.

Comment: @chris It's probably a typo that was perpetuated in the code. As you mentioned, I find hard to believe that a sane developer will rely on some archaic no-optimizing compiler.

Comment: @vsoftco : Hard to believe that I found it an official Axis tutorial.

Comment: @sjsam There were seriously stupid software bugs even in space probes [sent (and crashed) to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter), so you better believe it ;)

Comment: @vsoftco : Nice touch !! But it almost convinced me to believe that it's a return statement.

Comment: Fun fact, this is how return statements were written in TI-Basic graphing calculator programs.

Comment: If you look closely, that Axis final example is missing every keyword, such as return, while and if. It is syntaxically correct, but it will not work at all. My guess is the code listing has been created automatically, and it was supposed to color they keywords, instead of removing them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I expected this.. But Axis library is C which I am trying to port to a C++ project. was a bit confused how to tag it.. Please feel free to re-tag this.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen You nailed it! That's most likely why the "typos".

Comment: So you are compiling as C++? That's how to tag it.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen : The fact is that i overlooked the other statements when I saw `0;` which in a sense was striking. A second answer to the question points me to the right piece of code which is complete.

Comment: @n.m.: thankfully all those instances were in the tutorial code which is corrupted due to formatting issues. Source code looks fine. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ `return` can be omitted **only** in `main()` , in functions that return `void`, and in constructors and destructors. In the former case `main()` returns automatically `0`. In your case the statement `0;` is a syntactically correct statement, evaluated as a no-op, so the compiler is basically ignoring it.

Comment: Please feel free to change the title of the question if needed.

Comment: <pedantic> ...and in constructors and destructors. </pedantic>

Comment: @T.C. Correct as always ;) Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find that code? It seems like it's corrupted, perhaps due to formatting for showing it on a web page or something...?

The original code (from https://github.com/bnoordhuis/axis2-c/blob/master/axiom/test/util/axiom_util_test.c) is:

```
int main()
{
    int status = AXIS2_SUCCESS;
    axutil_env_t *env = NULL;
    status = build_and_serialize_om(env);

    if(status == AXIS2_FAILURE)
    {
        printf(" build AXIOM failed");
    }

    axutil_env_free(env);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it !! Thank you. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) And hey, for answering the question, give your +1 to vsoftco. And for finding the root cause, give your +1 to me :D !!